# Update child component from parent component react

Tags: reactjs, react-component

Hi I am new to react and I have some situation. I would like to update data from parent to child but child data change will not update to parent.

Here is my parent component =>

```
export default class ShiftMaster extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
    monshift : new TempShift(),
}


   }

handelChange = event =>{          

  this.setState({
      [event.target.id]:event.target.value  
  },()=>{

  });
}
                               <ShiftDaily                              

                                shiftday={this.state.monshift}
                                />
```

This is TempShift object

```
export class TempShift{
  constructor(
              offin_f=0,
              offout_f=0,
              offin_1h=0,
              offout_1h=0,
              offin_2h=0){
              this.offin_f = offin_f;
                this.offout_f = offout_f;
                this.offin_1h = offin_1h;
                this.offout_1h = offout_1h;
                this.offin_2h = offin_2h;
    }
```

This is Child component called ShiftDaily

```
export default class ShiftDaily extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
      super(props);

      this.state = {                  
              offin_f:props.shiftday.offin_f,
              offout_f:props.shiftday.offout_f,
                  offin_1h:props.shiftday.offin_1h,
                  offout_1h:props.shiftday.offout_1h,
                  offin_2h:props.shiftday.offin_2h}
    }

handleChange = event =>{     
    this.setState({

          [event.target.id]:event.target.value  

    },()=>{

    });
  }

<Form.Control   id="offout_f"
                            className="form-control-sm"                                              
                            value={this.state.offout_f} 
                            onChange={this.handleChange}/>
```

I can't pass the parent's handle change to child because when value change in child component will not be reflected in parent data.

But when I change in parent `monshift`, I would like to update to child value and show data. May I know how can I achieve this one? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use `props.*` states directly without assigning them to `this.state` inside `ShiftDaily`.

The reason is because `constructor` runs only once during render, thus any changes you make won't be reflected via `props.*` passed to `ShiftDaily` (because `this.state` is never updated again, as it was set once in the constructor)

So, you need to
1. Get rid of `constructor` and `this.state = {...}` assignment altogether.
2. Remove `ShiftDaily.handleChange`, as the props will be updated from `ShiftMaster` and trickle down to `ShiftDaily` on prop change.
3. Use `this.props.*` values directly.

```
    <Form.Control   
      id="offout_f"
      className="form-control-sm"                                              
      value={this.props.shiftday.offout_f} />
```

Comment: Thanks, I am trying as you suggest. According to your suggestions, May I know how to pass data from parent to child. Current passing is correct? Because this.props.offout_f always undefined. And I don't need change on child component?

Comment: @Jze I've updated the answer above. I was wrong because I used `this.props.offout_f` instead of `this.props.shiftday.offout_f`

Comment: Also, you can get more clarity and understanding of working of the same from the following links: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html, https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html